# Resume: Lots of experience, decade off from industry

Tags: resume, job-search, developer

I don't have a current resume to post, though I can throw one together to help with this question, but resume writing has never been my strong point to begin with.

That being said, I'm looking to get back into the tech sector (specifically project management or coder/development, even as an entry level position). I have a long history of experience and work history in the industry (from 1999 - 2007 that was pretty much all I did). However I didn't have the same work ethic, or proficiency that I do now, just enough to get by. I took several years to work freelance, go back to school, and work in other industries/start a few businesses to learn more of the business side and fill in gaps in my knowledge.

I have a great skill set, even a few freelance jobs to show as examples, and the ability to create more examples, but I'm not sure how to spin this on my resume to emphasize my returning to education, experience in management in other industries, etc. to where I feel it would inspire someone to take a look at me, and when I try for simple clerical/data entry positions hoping to work up I'm told that I'm 'overqualified'.

Does anyone have any experience with this, from the hiring side or the job seeking side?

Thanks!

Comment: I'd rather not an entry level position, but I'm worried that with 10 years out of the industry, apart from school and some freelance gigs, that that's all I'll be able to get at the moment.  I'm confident enough in my work ethic and skills to be feel ok working up from there.

I've read that cover letters don't usually get read (of course I've read other articles saying other things as well).  Would you recommend including the industry experience I did have and just explaining in the cover letter what I've been doing in the meantime?  Really not sure where to start.

Comment: If all you apply for is entry positions, that is certainly all you'll get. Apply for anything you think you"re qualified for and interested in, and let them decide whether you're worth talking to.

Comment: People take career detours all the time, and do just fine. Get someone who is excellent at resumes to coach you (or hire a pro). That said you will probably have more chance of success with small companies. Larger Corporations  tend to eschew career trajectories that aren't a straight line.

Answer (score 1):

In my view, being a decade off from industry does not mean that you've *lost* it. Your freelance jobs are hard evidence that you were still on track. You can put that in the Work Experience section in your résumé.

If I were the hiring manager, of course I would read first your cover letter. Always remember that cover letters leave a lot of impression.

My advice is, DO NOT settle for entry level positions as much as possible. Instead, build up your portfolio to help you get an edge over younger applicants. Remember that you are a senior person who should be in a senior position, given your skill sets.

Also, since you are in the IT industry, you must know the latest trends/technologies/practices. For example, many companies look for project managers who know *agile software development*. You must spend time reading many, many articles to keep up.